# Cleaning the Result of tshark into a nicer Readable CDP client

Tags: awk, grep, tshark

I am trying to get rid of the info I dont need from a command output, so that i can build a simple CDP client for linux. Right now, i am using grep to filter the results of tshark. The command i am running is:

`tshark -i enp0s25 -a duration:30 -V -f "ether host 01:00:0c:cc:cc:cc" -c 2 | grep -e "IP Address" -e "Device ID:" -e "Software version: Cisco IOS Software" -e "Port ID:" -e "VTP Management Domain:" -e "Native VLAN:" -e "Voice VLAN:" -e "Duplex:" -e "Power Available:"`

The results i get, are currently in this format:

```
    Device ID: SW17.241.host.local
    Device ID: SW17.241.host.local
    Software version: Cisco IOS Software, C3560 Software (C3560-IPSERVICESK9-M), Version 12.2(55)SE10, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc2)
        IP Address: 172.16.17.241
Port ID: FastEthernet0/3
VTP Management Domain: NAME
    VTP Management Domain: NAME
Native VLAN: 5
    Native VLAN: 5
Duplex: Full
    Duplex: Full
    Voice VLAN: 300
        IP Address: 172.16.17.241
Power Available: 
    Power Available: 0 mW
    Power Available: 4294967295 mW
Device ID: SW17.241.host.local
    Device ID: SW17.241.host.local
    Software version: Cisco IOS Software, C3560 Software (C3560-IPSERVICESK9-M), Version 12.2(55)SE10, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc2)
        IP Address: 172.16.17.241
Port ID: FastEthernet0/3
VTP Management Domain: NAME
    VTP Management Domain: NAME
Native VLAN: 5
    Native VLAN: 5
Duplex: Full
    Duplex: Full
    Voice VLAN: 300
        IP Address: 172.16.17.241
Power Available: 
    Power Available: 0 mW
    Power Available: 4294967295 mW
```

as you can see, i am getting a lot of repeated lines. I would like to get only one instance of each line. for example, the line "Power Available: "
does not need to be there. I only needed to see line that says         Power Available: 4294967295 mW
Also, the line "IP Address: 172.16.17.241" appear more than once. I only need it once.

I would like to see something like this:

`Device ID: 
Software Version: 
Port ID: 
VTP Management Domain: 
Native VLAN: 
Duplex: 
Voice VLAN: 
Power Available:`

Comment: Google says that "CPD client" is Continuous Professional Development of Client Relationships — could you please explain what is the meaning that you give to the "CPD" term?

Comment: Please show the exact expected result, this would help to give the answer quickly.

Comment: sorry. i meant CDP. (Cisco Discovery Protocol).

My expected results would be:

`Device ID:
Software Version:
Port ID:
VTP Management Domain:
Native VLAN:
Duplex:
Voice VLAN:
Power Available:`

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat awk-script
BEGIN{
  str="Device ID:Software version:Port ID:VTP Management Domain:Native VLAN:Duplex:Voice VLAN:Power Available.*[1-9]"
  split(str,s,":")
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=length(s);i++)
    if ($0 ~ s[i] && s[i]){
      s[i]=0;print $0
    }
}

$ tshark -i enp0s25 -a duration:30 -V -f "ether host 01:00:0c:cc:cc:cc" -c 2 | awk -f awk-script
    Device ID: SW17.241.host.local
    Software version: Cisco IOS Software, C3560 Software (C3560-IPSERVICESK9-M), Version 12.2(55)SE10, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc2)
Port ID: FastEthernet0/3
VTP Management Domain: NAME
Native VLAN: 5
Duplex: Full
    Voice VLAN: 300
    Power Available: 4294967295 mW
```

Brief explanation:

- Record all desired filtered values into `str`
- `Power Available.*[1-9]` to extract the line with non-zero value in lines contain  "Power Available"
- Traverse the file if the specific value has been hit, set the flag to '0'. So that they would be printed once for every filtered value

Comment: it works fine! except for Software version. That is not printing

Comment: Since the 'V' of "Software version" is lower case in your file. I modify it in the `str`, it should be fine now.

Comment: Cool. Im trying toi put it all in one single bash script. but, then, the $0 points to the script, instead of poiting to the command output. how can i solve that?

Comment: also, i am still getting `Type: Software version (0x0005) ` instead of `Software version: Cisco IOS etc...`

Comment: @yurividal $0 would adopt by `awk` first, so what you mentioned should not happen. Check your script. And try to add some regex beyond `Software version` in to `str` to filter what you want. You may reference the `Power Available.*[1-9]` in `str` in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys. I actually got it to work and even better, I made it work with tcpdump and the awk script suggested above. The result is on github:
http://github.com/yurividal/tuxCDP
Feel free to contribute